# Can't uninstall Jenkins no matter what I do

Tags: jenkins, homebrew

I'm trying to uninstall Jenkins because I'm stuck with the login page and I just can't get it to work properly. I've tried to remove it using the brew command `brew uninstall jenkins-lts` and at first it seemed to work but then after I visit localhost:8080 it is still there!

So I went to the ~/.jenkins folder and removed it...I don't have any Jenkins folder in /Application directory.

I even killed the running process at port 8080 with `lsof -t -i tcp:8080 | xargs kill`  but that is not working! Jenkins login page is still there.

How can I, once and for all, delete Jenkins?

Comment: Can't you try to use helm charts or docker compose to install Jenkins?

Comment: I've never used docker...Yesterday I was so pissed off about this Jenkins stuff that I bought a course on Udemy on Docker and started studying it so that I can use Jenkins and other things with it

Comment: I can give u instructions on how to deploy using docker compose or helm charts if required

Comment: I thank you for your help but I prefer to understand what I'm doing before doing anything wrong or suggested

Comment: Sure. So u want to use the docker way by going though it ? I am right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct